# Raphael.js how to store the name in each element?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have rendered several rectangulars in Raphael.js. I would like to give each of the rectangular a name, and store the name to each of them. How to do in Raphael?

For example:

```
var r1 = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50); //name it 'car'
var r2 = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50); //name it 'plane'
var r3 = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50); //name it 'bike'
```

then, in future, I can distinguish them by check the name, like `r1.attr('name')=='car'`

How to add new attribute to store the names then?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add an ID to the DOM object [using `.node`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#node)?

```
var r1,r2,r3;

r1 = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
r1.node.id = 'car'

r2 = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
r2.node.id = 'plane'

r3 = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
r3.node.id = 'bike'
```